# iCloud event invitation delivered by email instead of by calendar app

Tags: icloud, calendar

I can connect to icloud via two emails:

`xxxxxx@gmail.com` - primary, and `xxxxxx@icloud.com` - secondary. Is it important which email was used to invite me to event? On the device I can be logged via both of them to EXACTLY THE SAME ACCOUNT. Currently on the device I am logged in via `xxxxxx@icloud.com`. Shouldn't I get invitation in calendar app even an invitation was adressed to `xxxxxx@gmail.com`?

Because when invitation was sent to `@gmail.com` I was invited via email, otherwise I get notification via calendar app. Is not weird?

I need to understand this.

Comment: Have You set up Your gmail account to synchronize calendars?

Comment: In `Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars -> xxxxxx@gmail.com` Calendars is switched off. Shortly... I haven't.

Comment: Thats the reason why You do not get invites to the Calendar.app I suppose

Comment: You do not understand, it is not that, This options is whether to sync google calendar events in calendar app. The invitation from question is NOT from google, it is from APPLE, delivered via google account. That is the point. Shouldn't be like that.